# Compare value of SQL query

Tags: java, sql, if-statement, comparison

Need to compare the value obtained in my SQL query but the attribute that want to compare has N results that are: "Administrador", "Financeiro" and "Operacional". It was to run the IF in the code below, but I'm doing some wrong comparison and is running ELSE.

```
public void Logar(){

    String sql = "Select usuario_login, senha_login, nome_login, nivelAcesso from nivelAcessoSistema natural join login group by nivelAcesso having usuario_login = ? and senha_login = ?";

    try{

        pst = con.prepareStatement(sql); 

        pst.setString(1, txtUsuario.getText()); //Campo do usuário
        pst.setString(2, txtSenha.getText()); //Campo da senha

        rs = pst.executeQuery(); 

        if(rs.next()){ //Se existe registro no banco de dados com os dados informados na tela de login...

            String nivelAcesso = rs.getString("nivelAcesso"); //Comparando valor de atríbuto "nivelAcesso" do banco de dados

            if(nivelAcesso.equals("Administrador") && nivelAcesso.equals("Financeiro") && nivelAcesso.equals("Operacional")){

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "OK");
            }

            else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong");
            }
```

I hope you can help me on this.

Thank you.

Comment: It's convention to capitalize all of your SQL keywords, even though SQL is case-insensitive. For example, instead of `Select`, it's generally considered better practice to write `SELECT`. In addition, I've found this helps me a great deal with debugging.

Comment: It's true! Thanks newbiedoodle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Gustavo, can you try something like this and checks if this helps you?

```
static Set<String> valueSet;

static {
    valueSet = new HashSet<String>();
    valueSet.add("Administrador");
    valueSet.add("Financeiro");
    valueSet.add("Operacional");
}

public void Logar() {
    Set<String> result = new HashSet<String>();

    String sql = "Select usuario_login, senha_login, nome_login, nivelAcesso from nivelAcessoSistema natural join login group by nivelAcesso having usuario_login = ? and senha_login = ?";

    try {

        pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);

        pst.setString(1, txtUsuario.getText()); //Campo do usuário
        pst.setString(2, txtSenha.getText()); //Campo da senha

        rs = pst.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) { //Se existe registro no banco de dados com os dados informados na tela de login...

            String nivelAcesso = rs.getString("nivelAcesso"); //Comparando valor de atríbuto "nivelAcesso" do banco de dados

            result.add(nivelAcesso);
        }

        if (valueSet.containsAll(result)) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "OK");
        }

        else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong");
        }
    }
```

Comment: MgYaar, see another problem: I signed up a user in the database with nivelAcesso = "Operacional" and "Financeiro" but I can not access the Set <String> NIVELACESSOOperFin

Everytime I try to run the Set <String> NIVELACESSOOperFin is running NIVELACESSOOper that only have nivelAcesso = "Operacional"

See the code:

Answer (score 2):

The problem resides here:

```
     if(nivelAcesso.equals("Administrador") && nivelAcesso.equals("Financeiro")
 && nivelAcesso.equals("Operacional"))
```

nivelAcesso can't be equals to all these values at same time. Change this line to:

```
     if(nivelAcesso.equals("Administrador") || nivelAcesso.equals("Financeiro") 
|| nivelAcesso.equals("Operacional"))
```

for more information about logic comparisons, please read this:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html

Comment: But usuario_login has these three registered nivelAcesso: "Administrador", "Financeiro" and "Operacional". So I used && because I want to make the comparison if usuario_login has the 3 nivelAcesso

Answer (score 0):

```
if(nivelAcesso.equals("Administrador") && nivelAcesso.equals("Financeiro") && nivelAcesso.equals("Operacional")){
```

should be

```
if(nivelAcesso.equals("Administrador") || nivelAcesso.equals("Financeiro") || nivelAcesso.equals("Operacional")){
```

You need the *OR* rather than the *AND* operator:

```
nivelAcesso.equals("Administrador")
```

**and**

```
nivelAcesso.equals("Financeiro")
```

can never both be true at the same time.

Comment: But usuario_login has these three registered nivelAcesso: "Administrador", "Financeiro" and "Operacional". So I used && because I want to make the comparison if usuario_login has the 3 nivelAcesso

Comment: Okay, but the string `nivelAcesso` can't be three things at once, which is what you're checking. It can't be "Administrador" and "Financeiro" at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

**OPTION 1**
You can use fixed set of constants or even apply `enum` and use [EnumSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html)

For example:

```
static final Set<String> importantRoleSet = new HashSet<String(){{
    add("Administrador");
    add("Financeiro");
    ....
}};
```

After that in your code:

```
...
if( importantRoleSet.contains(nivelAcesso) ){
   //do the role-related operations
}
```

**OPTION 2**

Place this logic to SQL and select already defined 0/1 for correct role:

```
SELECT nivelAcesso in ('Administrador', 'Financeiro') as isInRole FROM ...
```

In this case you create new field `isInRole` - that will contain 0 or 1 depending if nivelAcesso is one of permitted values

Answer (score 0):

@Gustavo, It looks like you want to compare the value that you got from database, and values will be just any one of these "Administrador" or "Financeiro" or "Operacional". So, to compare these, you need to use "||" rather than "&&" in your `IF` condition. For example: query

`"Select usuario_login, senha_login, nome_login, nivelAcesso from nivelAcessoSistema natural join login group by nivelAcesso having usuario_login = ? and senha_login = ?"`

returns nivelAcesso="Administrador" then your code will be like:

```
if(nivelAcesso.equals("Administrador") || nivelAcesso.equals("Financeiro") || nivelAcesso.equals("Operacional")){

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "OK");
        }
```

In this case, it will result true and will enter in `IF` block.

Comment: MgYaar, that's the problem! Because I can only perform the desired task if the usuario_login have these 3 nivelAcesso

Comment: usuario_login have these 3 nivelAcesso registered in the database. Now how do I compare this case? Because I can only run the IF case of the task if the usuario_login is identified with the 3 nivelAcesso

Comment: @Gustavo, that means your query will result you 3 result sets from database. Firstly, make a SET of these 3 values "Administrador", "Financeiro", "Operacional". Then, Iterate the data that you have fetched from database using loop, create a new SET of nivelAcesso values. Now, compare these 2 SETs. If both are same, then you are good to go. I hope this would give you some hint.

Answer (score 0):

I signed up a user in the database with nivelAcesso = "Operacional" and "Financeiro" but I can not access the Set  NIVELACESSOOperFin Everytime I try to run the Set  NIVELACESSOOperFin is running NIVELACESSOOper that only have nivelAcesso = "Operacional" See the code:

```
Set<String> NIVELACESSOOperFin; {

    NIVELACESSOOperFin = new HashSet<String>();
    NIVELACESSOOperFin.add("Operacional");
    NIVELACESSOOperFin.add("Financeiro");
}

Set<String> NIVELACESSOOper; {

    NIVELACESSOOper = new HashSet<String>();
    NIVELACESSOOper.add("Operacional");
}

Set<String> NIVELACESSOAdmFinOper; {

    NIVELACESSOAdmFinOper = new HashSet<String>();
    NIVELACESSOAdmFinOper.add("Administrador");
    NIVELACESSOAdmFinOper.add("Financeiro");
    NIVELACESSOAdmFinOper.add("Operacional");
}


public void Logar() {

    Set<String> result = new HashSet<String>();

    String sql = "SELECT usuario_login, senha_login, nome_login, nivelAcesso FROM nivelAcessoSistema NATURAL JOIN login GROUP BY usuario_login HAVING usuario_login = ? AND senha_login = ?";

    try {

        pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);

        pst.setString(1, txtUsuario.getText()); //Campo do usuário
        pst.setString(2, txtSenha.getText()); //Campo da senha

        rs = pst.executeQuery();

        if (rs.next()) { //Se existe registro no banco de dados com os dados informados na tela de login...

            String nivelAcesso = rs.getString("nivelAcesso"); //Comparando valor de atríbuto "nivelAcesso" do banco de dados

            result.add(nivelAcesso);

            if (NIVELACESSOOper.containsAll(result)) {

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Operacional");
            }

            else if(NIVELACESSOOperFin.containsAll(result)){

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Operacional - Financeiro");
            }

            else if (NIVELACESSOAdmFinOper.containsAll(result)) {

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Operacional - Financeiro - Administrativo");
            }
```